# How to Format text within bracket for RichTextBox?

Tags: vb.net, string, richtextbox

I have a string like : **[1] Happy New year [2] Happy Birthday [3] Happy Together**
And I want to format the number 1,2,3 as Red Color. So I put the string to a RichTextBox and do the search and format like the code below:
(What I do is, find "[" and "]" and save to a Global variable (i,j), then everytime I get a new set of i,j the formating event fired. However, it does not do what I expected. : (

```
Public i, j As Integer
 Dim s As String = "[1] Happy New year [2] Happy Birthday [3] Happy Together"

'Button Code
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim count As Integer = 0
        rtfbuffer.Text = s
        rtfbuffer.Font = New Font("Tahoma", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
        rtfbuffer.ForeColor = Color.Black

        Do While count < s.Length - 1


            If s.Chars(count) = "[" Then
                i = count
                count += 1
            ElseIf s.Chars(count) = "]" Then
                j = count + 1

                count += 1
                rtfbuffer.Select(i, j)
                rtfbuffer.SelectionColor = Color.Red

            Else
                count += 1
            End If

            Loop
```

Finally, I could get only First text within the "[ ]" Red.. Look at the code, I could not understand why it does not go through the reamaining text. could you show me how to correct it? 
Thank you very much ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to the `Select` method is the length of the text to select. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4fh98s(v=vs.110).aspx).

Public Sub Select (
    start As Integer,
    length As Integer
)

> Parameters
>
> start Type: System.Int32 The position of the first character in the current text selection within the text box.
>
> length Type: System.Int32 The number of characters to select.

So, in your code, when you call `Select` you can calculate the length to select (and then highlight) by providing `j - i` instead of just `j`. It works for the first time in your code, because the 'end index' (`j`) is actually the same as the length i.e. 3.

```
rtfbuffer.Select(i, j - i)
rtfbuffer.SelectionColor = Color.Red
```

Comment: That's correct. @Robin. Great answer ~ ^^". Thank you very much ~